solve this Github push command issue?
Every time while pushing my code on Github  in a repository I have to generate a token before git push origin master command and if I directly try to push by entering my password I see this message for authentication. How  to solve this issue?
This message appears in terminal when password is entered:

Support for password authentication was removed Github Fixed using Token (August 13, 2021)

I tried everything but there is no other option than generating a token.

Create a token without expire date. You can reuse it.
